# Search .htaccess redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to do the following redirection:

FROM:

```
https://www.example.com/?s=busqueda
```

TO:

```
https://www.example.com/?s=busqueda&post_type=product&dgwt_wcas=1
```

I tried with:

```
RewriteCond% {QUERY_STRING} s = (.*)
RewriteRule ^ $?S=%1&post_type=product&dgwt_wcas=1[NE]
```

But it does not work! If anyone has any idea why, I appreciate the explanation :)

Comment: You've injected _spaces_ all over your code sample (I expect to prevent auto-linking), but this just makes it unreadable. Format code blocks using 4-space indentation ot 3-backticks (GitHub style). Please edit your question to correct this formatting, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(I assume the double slash at the start of the URL-path in the destination URL is a typo?)

Try the following near the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(s=busqueda)$
RewriteRule ^$ /?%1&post_type=product&dgwt_wcas=1 [R=302,L]
```

It looks like you were probably quite close in your attempt, however, since you were missing start/end anchors (`^` and `$`) on the *CondPattern* when matching the query string it would have resulted in a redirect/rewrite loop.

The directive you posted is also a rewrite, not a "redirect" as you stated in your question.

Comment: if it was typing error.
Thank you very much for your time and for the explanation, I will try it!